# Flat file error handling

Tags: ssis, etl

I researching about Integration Service as ETL solutions. My application will read some positional flat files and import them to database, but is a very-known fact, sometimes files came with bad characters and I need to show up in some log where this bad characters are in file (which line and which position in the line).

This can be done with SSIS?

Comment: what do you mean? The question is tagged in SSIS and ETL.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: yes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, ee are working in a new version, made from scratch, of an application that was entirely built by our dev team, and this file parser was a pain-in-the-ass to make.

Comment: you can redirect your error data to another component in SSIS. for example, there are 5 rows in your file, one is invalid, only 4 can insert into the destniation, you can add set the error output of your destniation, and redirect the error data into another component, like another flat file.